# dns - Only specific DNS nameservers work in Debian 10, none others

Tags: debian, dns, ipv6

I have an IPv6-only VPS running Debian 10 Buster from [EUServ](https://euserv.com/).

To access the IPv4 internet through the VPS, I used [this NAT64 handoff service](https://v6tools.kasperd.dk/nat64handoff/service) by adding their nameservers to my `/etc/resolv.conf` and it just magically worked.

Recently, I could not access the IPv4 internet through the VPS due to `Temporary failure in name resolution` errors. Since I figured this might be a problem with the nameservers, I removed all nameservers from `/etc/resolv.conf` and added just Google's IPv6 Public DNS nameservers. Even after adding those, DNS resolution did not work and every hostname (even IPv6 enabled websites) I tried to ping returned a `Temporary failure in name resolution` error:

```
$ ping google.com
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
```

However, pinging  IP addresses directly does work as expected:

```
$ ping 2a00:1098:2b::1
PING 2a00:1098:2b::1(2a00:1098:2b::1) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2a00:1098:2b::1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=15.0 ms
64 bytes from 2a00:1098:2b::1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=17.1 ms
64 bytes from 2a00:1098:2b::1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=14.9 ms
^C
--- 2a00:1098:2b::1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 4ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 14.850/15.624/17.053/1.016 ms
```

After experimenting with several public IPv6 DNS nameservers, I found out the only nameservers that work in this VPS are the default ones found in `/etc/resolv.conf` right after a fresh re-installation of Debian 10:

```
search blue.kundencontroller.de
options rotate
nameserver 2a02:180:6:5::1c
nameserver 2a02:180:6:5::1d
nameserver 2a02:180:6:5::1e
nameserver 2a02:180:6:5::4
```

The above nameservers enable the VPS to access the IPv6 internet (like ping google.com), but I can't access any IPv4-only host since there is no NAT64-DNS64 service being used; moreover, I have no idea why any other DNS nameserver except these few do not work in this VPS. I will provide any logs/info needed to debug this.

Comment: I suspect you’ll have to ask your VPS provider...

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on IPv6 only, the way you contact the IPv4 internet is by resolving names with a special namerserver (DNS64) that returns an IPv6 address that has a fixed IPv6 prefix and the actual IPv4 address at the end:

```
IPv6 address = IPv6 private prefix + IPv4 address
```

When the VPS routing sees the special IPv6 prefix, it strips the IPv6 part and uses the IPv4 part, that is then sent on to the IPv4 internet. That process is NAT64.

So, unless you use their name servers you are stuck in an IPv6 world until they solve your issue (you should contact them).